# Capitalization after upper-case abbrevation in Go variable name

Tags: go, naming-conventions, variable-names, mixed-case

Should a struct field be named `HTTPClient` or `HTTPclient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have HTTP and Client so HTTPClient, and, for lower case, httpClient.

Comment: Why is `fmt.Fprintf` than not named `fmt.FPrintF`?

Comment: @R3turnz: `fmt.Fprintf` is from the C language function name `fprintf`.